# Compile error Chaiscript Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio-2015, compilation, chaiscript

[image]

The error:

```
Error   C2664   'void chaiscript::detail::Dispatch_Engine::add(const chaiscript::Type_Info &,const std::string &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'double (__cdecl *const )(int,double)' to 'const chaiscript::Proxy_Function &'   Chaiscript  c:\users\kung\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\chaiscript\chaiscript\language\chaiscript_engine.hpp    764
```

The example code:

```
//main.cpp
#include "chaiscript/chaiscript.hpp"

double function(int i, double j)
{
  return i * j;
}

int main()
{
  chaiscript::ChaiScript chai;
  chai.add(&function, "function");

  double d = chai.eval<double>("function(3, 4.75);");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `chaiscript::fun()` call in your test.

```
chai.add(chaiscript::fun(&function), "function");
```

I strongly suggest you start with the complete example provided on the [examples page](http://chaiscript.com/examples.html#ChaiScript_Compiled_in_Stdlib_Example):

```
#include <chaiscript/chaiscript.hpp>
#include <chaiscript/chaiscript_stdlib.hpp>

std::string helloWorld(const std::string &t_name)
{
  return "Hello " + t_name + "!";
}

int main()
{
  chaiscript::ChaiScript chai(chaiscript::Std_Lib::library());
  chai.add(chaiscript::fun(&helloWorld), "helloWorld");

  chai.eval("puts(helloWorld(\"Bob\"));");
}
```

Otherwise you'll quickly run into another error when you wonder why it cannot find the standard library.